# How to create a AVD device in eclipse

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have done the setup of my AVD device. So when I running this avd it is showing me unfortunately launcher has stopped.Can any one please let me know how we can resolve this problem and how to increase the size of AVD vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window->AVD->New->AVD Name, give as you wish and then select Device based on your requirement size. 4.7" or 3" or 7" select it.

Or you can also custom size by selecting Device Definition of second tab in AVD.Double click it and customize it and you can use it.

Comment: When I am selecting Nexus 7 screen size is 4.0.and resolution in 800 X 1280 the device is not completely visible in my system screen completely.I want to reduce it's size How can we do that

Comment: Please add the screen shot of the device configuration so that I can do that .I am new in android

Answer (score 0):

In the [Managing Virtual Devices](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html), there's a section for [Managing AVDs with AVD Manager](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html). Try getting to know them first. You should also check [Android Emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html).

Comment: When I am selecting Nexus 7 screen size is 4.0.and resolution in 800 X 1280 the device is not completely visible in my system screen completely.I want to reduce it's size How can we do that

Comment: You can do this by adding custom dimensions to the screen, but this will not give you the correct results visually. Try dragging it if you can't chenge your system resolution to 1600 x 1200 pixels for example.

Comment: You can define a scaling! Use that to decrease the real size... but be aware that scaling will effect the way your layout looks. It might be that you don't see borders/lines etc the way they are. Especially 1px lines might be completely invisible...

Comment: In that I a giving screen size to 7.0 and monitor dpi 118.Then the vertical size is reduced and horizontal size in increased

Answer (score 0):

Use genymotion it was release on the droidcon in Paris and it is superfast. There is one article of cyrilmottier that explain why u should use it.

http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/06/27/a-productive-android-development-environment/

Download from here:

http://www.genymotion.com

And the user guide is in here:

https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/doc/